# Google TV Emulator with Android 3.2

Tags: android, google-tv

I'm trying to test the compatibily of HLS on GoogleTV and i read that the new Google TV are going to have Android 3.2, that is compatible with HLS, i install the Google TV plugin for eclipse, but the only version of Android that seem to have is 3.1.

The HLS doesn't work on that version, so i want to know if it's possible to download a version of the emulator with 3.2 or do something to have Android 3.2 in the GoogleTV Emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google TV add-on is not yet available for Android 3.2; however, in general, support for testing video playback using the emulator is limited.  For testing HLS, you best option will be to contact the Google TV developer relations team.

Comment: You can email me. Or use Google+ to send me your email address.